# UBUNTU 18.04 Server: multiple netplan route-policy rules, but only one works

Tags: networking, server, netplan

UBUNTU SERVER 18.04 LTS with 2 GE NICs

```
eno1: 172.22.1.1/20
eno2: 10.11.1.34/30
```

netplan yaml:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      addresses: [ 172.22.1.1/20 ]
      gateway4: 172.22.0.1
      nameservers:
          addresses:
          - "172.22.0.53"
      routing-policy:
        - to: 172.22.224.0/19
          table: 211
          priority: 10
        - to: 192.168.201.0/24
          table: 200
          priority: 20
      routes:
        - to: 0.0.0.0/0
          via: 172.22.0.254
          table: 211
        - to: 0.0.0.0/0
          via: 172.22.0.1
          table: 200

    eno2:
      addresses: [ 10.11.1.34/30 ]
      routing-policy:
        - from: 10.11.1.34
          table: 222
          priority: 8
        - to: 10.128.0.0/16
          table: 222
          priority: 5
      routes:
        - to: 0.0.0.0/0
          via: 10.11.1.33
          table: 222
```

When I apply the configuration, restart the networking or use `netplan apply`, only one of these routing-policies works:

When I use `netplan apply`:

1. `eno1`:

   - First time, only the first routing-policy works.
   - Second time, only the second routing-policy works.
   - Third time, only the first routing-policy works.
2. `eno2`

   - Every time, only the second routing-policy works.

I wrote the yaml file as the [netplan.io examples](https://netplan.io/) told.

Comment: it is hard to know what is the gateway for eno2, but I feel like it shouldn't be ` via: 10.11.1.33` generally the gateway is 1

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it will work.

Here my suggestion of `netplan yaml`:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      addresses: [ 172.22.1.1/20 ]
      gateway4: 172.22.0.1
      nameservers:
          addresses:
          - "172.22.0.53"
      routing-policy:
        - from: 172.22.1.1
          to: 172.22.224.0/19
          table: 221
        - from: 172.22.1.1
          to: 192.168.201.0/24
          table: 201
      routes:
        - to: 0.0.0.0/0
          via: 172.22.0.254
          table: 221
        - to: 0.0.0.0/0
          via: 172.22.0.1
          table: 201
        - to: 172.22.224.0/19
          via: 172.22.0.254
        - to: 192.168.201.0/24
          via: 172.22.0.1
    eno2:
      addresses: [ 10.11.1.34/30 ]
      routing-policy:
        - from: 10.11.1.34
          table: 222
      routes:
        - to: 0.0.0.0/0
          via: 10.11.1.33
          table: 222
        - to: 10.128.0.0/16
          via: 10.11.1.33
```

Answer (score 0):

The below worked for me on a system with two network cards, each using a different gateway, interface and IP:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      addresses: 
        - 172.22.1.1/20
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
#      addresses: [ 172.22.1.1/20 ]
#      gateway4: 172.22.0.1
      nameservers:
          addresses: [172.22.0.53]
#          - "172.22.0.53"
      routes:
        - to: 0.0.0.0/0
          via: 172.22.0.254
          table: 200
          metric: 100
#          table: 211
        - to: 0.0.0.0/0
          via: 172.22.0.1
          table: 200
          metric: 100
        - to: 172.22.1.0/20
          via: 172.22.0.1
          table: 200
          on-link: true
      routing-policy:
        - to: 172.22.224.0/19
          table: 200
#          table: 211
          priority: 10
        - to: 192.168.201.0/24
          table: 200
          priority: 20

    eno2:
      addresses:
        - 10.11.1.34/30
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      nameservers:
          addresses: [???.???.???.???]
#      addresses: [ 10.11.1.34/30 ]
      routes:
        - to: 10.11.1.0/30
          via: 10.11.1.33
          table: 222
          on-link: true
        - to: 0.0.0.0/0
          via: 10.11.1.33
          table: 222
          metric: 100
          on-link:true
      routing-policy:
        - from: 10.11.1.34
          table: 222
          priority: 8
        - to: 10.128.0.0/16
          table: 222
          priority: 5
```

It is useful to run the following command to check for changes and see possible errors:

```
sudo netplan --debug apply
```